# Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined using webservice

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i have this error from the tutorial in http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12992/android-mysql-php-json-part-2-setting-up-a-xampp-server-and-mysql/

When i click the register button, this line of statement appears: Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Also in this tutorial, they are using XAMPP while i am using WAMP, i have a connection in the database but does it affect something if I use WAMP instead of XAMPP?

this is the simple code from the tutorial

```
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//If the username or password is empty when the user submits
//the form, the page will die.
//Using die isn't a very good practice, you may want to look into
//displaying an error message within the form instead.  
//We could also do front-end form validation from within our Android App,
//but it is good to have a have the back-end code do a double check.
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {


    // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Please Enter Both a Username and Password.";

    //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
    //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
    //app will parse
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//if the page hasn't died, we will check with our database to see if there is
//already a user with the username specificed in the form.  ":user" is just
//a blank variable that we will change before we execute the query.  We
//do it this way to increase security, and defend against sql injections
$query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
//now lets update what :user should be
$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username']
);

//Now let's make run the query:
try {
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //You eventually want to comment out the above die and use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//fetch is an array of returned data.  If any data is returned,
//we know that the username is already in use, so we murder our
//page
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    die("This username is already in use");
    //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
//create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
//Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $_POST['password']
);

//time to run our query, and create the user
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // Again, don't display $ex->getMessage() when you go live. 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
//a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
//redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
//json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
//the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);

//for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
//header("Location: login.php"); 
//die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors:

Note the parameter names you're using here: `:name` and `:pass`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";
```

Which you then totally ignore when you try to define values for those parameters:

```
$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $_POST['password']
);
```

The parameter names MUST match in both sections. You're putting in parameters that never get values assigned, and assigning values to parameters that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) VALUES ( :user, :pass ) ";

 //Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
':user' => $_POST['username'],
':pass' => $_POST['password']
);
```